# Fetch Link field Label and Link separately in views-view-fields template

Tags: views, theming

How can I fetch label and link field in views-view-fields--VIEW-NAME-HERE.html.twig file

So far I have tried

```
{{ fields.field_action_link.content }} give me the anchor tag prebuilt (html)
{{ fields.field_action_link.0.url }}
{{ content.field_action_link[0]['#url'] }}
```

but none of them seems to work for me. I am able to retrieve all other fields including image field.

Comment: Are you tried twig debug option.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Just edit the Link field and select these two options (highlighted in screenshot)